# Sequelize: Select all where value is the highest

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js, roles

I have a many-to-many relationship between **Users** and **Roles**. Since each User can have more than one role, I created a field, in the Role table, called `"clearance"`, that can be 0 to 3, which is a number that represents how high the Role is in the hierarchy.
There is a point in my server where I need to have the Users to include only the Role with the highest clearance. I've tried multiple uses of `sequelize.fn('MAX', sequelize.col('clearance")` in `where`, `include` and `through` objects, from Sequelize, to no avail. I am no expert in mysql nor in Sequelize, but it's the best js module I found to work as an ORM for my DB.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (no guarantee but looks like very close to what you want to achieve):

```js
const users = await Users.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Roles,
    limit: 1,
    order: ['clearance', 'DESC']
  }]
})
```

Comment: That array syntax doesn't work.
And It got me this Error
```Error: Only HasMany associations support include.separate```
Both models have ```belongsToMany``` relationships with each other

Comment: Fixed by adding `{}`